# HTTP-Response in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a problem with flutter. I want to get the HTTP-Response from a website, but it doesn´t work. The example works with other websites, but not with the required website.
Code:

```
Future initiate() async {
var client = Client();
Response response = await client.get(
‘https://www.phwt.de’
);
```

I get this error:

```
E/flutter (18017): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
E/flutter (18017): CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:352))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens because flutter does not know who signed or issued the certificate for `www.phwt.de`. The certificate seems to have been signed by SwissSign AG, to make it work you have these options:

1. Install the issuer's appropriate certificate ([SwissSign](https://www.swisssign.com/de/support/ca-prod.html)) system-wide (this is OS specific).
2. Either add the above certificates or `www.phwt.de`'s certificate to flutter/dart list's of trusted certificates (more info [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191101220942/https://dart-lang.github.io/server/tls-ssl.html#trusting-additional-cas) and [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/SecurityContext-class.html)):

```dart
SecurityContext clientContext = new SecurityContext()
    ..setTrustedCertificates(file: 'my_trusted_certificates.pem');
var client = new HttpClient(context: clientContext);
var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.phwt.de"));
var response = await request.close();
```

3. Trust the certificate in the code itself by setting a callback to `client.badCertificateCallback` and checking if the signature matches (see [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient/badCertificateCallback.html))
4. Same as 3 but you don't check anything and just return `true`, effectively making any certificate in the world valid (this is potentially dangerous).

Comment: Good answer, but (1) and (2) won't work here because of a problem with the server. (3 and 4 *do* work in this case.) The server problem is that its certificate chain is corrupt. As you say, the leaf certificate is signed by swisssign so you would expect the server to present the chain phwt.de->swisssign silver ca 2014->swisssign silver g2 root CA. However, whoever installed the certificate in the server made a mistake and it is presenting phwt.de->comodo RSA domain validation CA->comodo RSA CA. You can confirm this with openssl or wireshark. Unless this is fixed methods 1 and 2 will not work.