# Add Certificate in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter, certificate, httpresponse, pem

I want to get a Http-response from the Website 'https://www.phwt.de'. I tried to add the certificate in Flutter, but it doesn't work. The pem-file was added into the directory 'assets/Certificates' and it was added in pubspec.yaml. The error is, that the file cannot be opened.

```
Future initiate() async {
  SecurityContext clientContext = new SecurityContext()
    ..setTrustedCertificates('assets/Certificates/personal.pem');
  var client = new HttpClient(context: clientContext);
  var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.phwt.de"));
  var response = await request.close();

  return response;
}
```

Error:
OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP-Response in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58665747/http-response-in-flutter)

Comment: See that comment on the answer of the linked question. This solution will not work unless that server has fixed its certificate chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it as binary data:

```dart
  ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/Certificates/personal.pem');
  SecurityContext clientContext = new SecurityContext()
    ..setTrustedCertificatesBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Set SecurityContext to not trust the OS's certificates
   SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false);

  // Load certificate file
   ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/cert/Certificate.pem');

   SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
  // Trust the certificate
   context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
```